# SSH times outs after few secs between two Virtual Machines created under GCE

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Created two VM under Google Compute Engine and trying to do SSH for transferring files between them using SCP. But SSH times outs after few sec between two virtual machines 
Tried all the flags options in sshd_config and ssh_config, but still its not working

Comment: can you ping each other machine? Are there firewalls?

Comment: Yes ping is working fine....

Comment: SSH port 22 and 443 is also opened